# Why doesn't stackexchange.com have information about Stack Exchange?

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, stackexchange.com

http://stackexchange.com is devoid of anything that explains what the SE platform is. While it does show hot questions for logged out users, there's nothing, *except in the title bar*, that explains

1. that SE is a Q/A network
2. that SE is community-driven
3. that new sites can be proposed at A51

At the very least, these 3 things should exist on the `about` page (along with some other information), which shouldn't redirect to the management page.

Comment: google doesn't say on its home page that it's a search engine =)

Comment: It does say Search, just like SE says: Ask Question

Comment: @Kop My point is that if new users stumble across SE (through friends, Twitter, etc.) and weren't pointed to a specific site, they wouldn't understand what SE is. Everyone knows what Google is.

Comment: @Ivo I'm not talkin about the sites themselves, but the SE homepage. There's no "Ask Question" link there.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The first few times you go to stackexchange.com, you see the following:

> ##What is this?##

> Stack Exchange is a **network of free,
> community-driven Q&A sites**. We
> highlight and aggregate the best
> recent content from our entire network
> here. [Log in](https://stackexchange.com/users/login) to [create tag
> sets](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/11/tag-sets-on-stack-exchange/) to view questions on subjects
> that interest you.
>
> Wish we had Q&A on a different topic?
> Help us create new Q&A sites through
> the open, democratic process at [Area
> 51](http://area51.stackexchange.com/). For more information, check
> out [the blog](http://blog.stackexchange.com/) or read more [about
> us](https://stackoverflow.com/about/management).

But right now we don't really see stackexchange.com as the entrance point to the network.  Most people will find out about Stack Exchange by visiting one of the actual Q&A sites, and only later realize that it's part of a larger network.  Putting it another way, if I were telling someone about Stack Exchange, I wouldn't send them to stackexchange.com, I'd send them to [Stack Overflow](http://stackoverflow.com), or [Gaming](http://gaming.stackexchange.com), or [Cooking](http://cooking.stackexchange.com), etc.

StackExchange.com is more for power users of the network, to give them tools to manage all of the sites they're interested in with the [Hot Questions page](https://stackexchange.com/questions/all) and [Tag Sets](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/11/tag-sets-on-stack-exchange/), or track their placement in the [Reputation Leagues](https://stackexchange.com/leagues).

---

##Edit##

Joel also wrote a very nice [about page](https://stackexchange.com/about) a few weeks ago.